# Set MAC address in Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch

Prior to raspbian stretch, the best way to configure an ethernet interface MAC address was within /etc/network/interfaces, adding the line `hwaddress ether 00:e0:4c:53:44:50`.

At the moment I am having to set them via root crontab e.g. `@restart ifconfig eth1 down && ifconfig eth1 hw ether 00:e0:4c:53:44:50 && ifconfig eth1 up`

Can I configure an interface within /etc/dhcpcd.conf to achieve the same result, as attempting the old way causes havoc.....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dmitry Grigoryev, I followed his link to solve as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/00-mac.link
```

`[Match]
 MACAddress=original MAC
 [Link]
 MACAddress=spoofed MAC
 NamePolicy=kernel database onboard slot path`

I had previously tried macchanger, but it mysteriously reverted back to original for no apparent reason.